# Implementation of inverse kinematics solution in c++

Tags: inverse-kinematics, c++

I am having some issue with implementing a least square solution of the inverse kinematics problem.

The q configuration I get are rather large, or makes no sense, so I was hoping someone here could help me find my error in my program.

```
rw::math::Q pathPlanning::invKin(double dx, double dy , double dz)
{

    rw::kinematics::State state =  this->state;
    rw::math::Transform3D<> t_tool_base =  this->device.get()->baseTend(state);


    cout << t_tool_base.R().e() << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << t_tool_base.P().e() << endl;
    cout << endl;

    Eigen::MatrixXd jq(this->device.get()->baseJend(state).e().cols(), this->device.get()->baseJend(state).e().rows());
    jq =  this->device.get()->baseJend(state).e();


    //Least square solver - dq = [j(q)]T (j(q)[j(q)]T)⁻1 du  <=> dq = A*du
    Eigen::MatrixXd A (6,6);
    //A = jq.transpose()*(jq*jq.transpose()).inverse();
    A = (jq*jq.transpose()).inverse()*jq.transpose();

    std::vector<rw::math::Transform3D<> > out = sphere(dx,dy,dz);

    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("q_conf.txt", std::ios_base::app);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= out.size() ; ++i )
    {
        rw::math::Vector3D<> dif_p = out[i].P()-t_tool_base.P();

        Eigen::Matrix3d dif = out[i].R().e()- t_tool_base.R().e();
        rw::math::Rotation3D<> dif_r(dif);
        rw::math::RPY<> dif_rot(dif_r);

        Eigen::VectorXd du(6);
        du(0) = dif_p[0];
        du(1) = dif_p[1];
        du(2) = dif_p[2];

        du(3) = dif_rot[0];
        du(4) = dif_rot[1];
        du(5) = dif_rot[2];

        Eigen::VectorXd q(6);
        q = A*du;

        rw::math::Q q_current;
        q_current = this->device->getQ(this->state);
        rw::math::Q dq(q);
        rw::math::Q q_new = q_current+ dq;

        //cout << jq << endl;
        //cout << endl;
        //std::string text = "setQ{"  + to_string(q_new[0])  + ", " + to_string(q_new[1]) + ", " + to_string(q_new[2]) + ", " + to_string(q_new[3]) + ", " + to_string(q_new[4]) + ", " + to_string(q_new[5]) + "}";
        //cout << text << endl;
        //outfile << text << endl;

    }

    rw::math::Q bla(6); //Just used the text file for debugging purposes,  Which why I just return a random Q config.
    return bla;
}


rw::math::Transform3D<> pathPlanning::transform(double obj_x, double obj_y, double obj_z, double sphere_x, double sphere_y ,double sphere_z)
{
    // Z-axis should be oriented towards the object.
    // Rot consist of 3 direction vector [x,y,z] which describes how the axis should be oriented in the world space.
    // Looking at the simulation the z-axis is the camera out. X, and Y describes the orientation of the camera.
    // The vector are only for direction purposes, so they have to be normalized....
    // TODO: case [0  0 -1]... Why is it happening at what can be done to undo it?

    rw::math::Vector3D<> dir_z((obj_x - sphere_x), (obj_y - sphere_y), (obj_z - sphere_z));
    dir_z = normalize(dir_z);
    rw::math::Vector3D<> downPlane(0.0,0.0,-1.0);
    rw::math::Vector3D<> dir_x = cross(downPlane,dir_z);
    dir_x = normalize(dir_x);
    rw::math::Vector3D<> dir_y = cross(dir_z,dir_x);
    dir_y = normalize(dir_y);

    rw::math::Rotation3D<> rot_out (dir_x,dir_y,dir_z);

    rw::math::Vector3D<> pos_out(sphere_x,sphere_y,sphere_z);

    rw::math::Transform3D<> out(pos_out,rot_out);
    return out;
}

std::vector<rw::math::Transform3D<>> pathPlanning::sphere(double dx, double dy, double dz)
{
    double r = 0.50; // Radius of the sphere -  set to 0.50 cm (TODO: has to be checked if that also is accurate)
    cout << "Create a sphere" << endl;

    double current_x = this->device->baseTend(this->state).P()[0];
    double current_y = this->device->baseTend(this->state).P()[1];
    double current_z = this->device->baseTend(this->state).P()[2];

    rw::math::Vector3D<> center(current_x + dx, current_y + dy , current_z + dz);

    // Formula for sphere (x-x0)²+(y-y0)²+(z-z0)²=r²
    // x: x = x_0 + rcos(theta)sin(phi)
    // y: y = y_0 + rsin(theta)sin(phi)
    // z: z = z_0 + rcos(phi)
    // Angle range: 0 <= theta <= 2M_PI ; 0 <= phi <= M_PI

    double obj_x = current_x + dx;
    double obj_y = current_y + dy;
    double obj_z = current_z + dz;

    ofstream positions;
    ofstream rotations_z;
    ofstream rotations_y;
    ofstream rotations_x;
    positions.open ("sphere_positions.csv");
    rotations_z.open("z_dir.csv");
    rotations_y.open("y_dir.csv");
    rotations_x.open("x_dir.csv");
    std::vector<rw::math::Transform3D<>> out;

    int count = 32;
    for(double theta = 0; theta <= 2*M_PI ; theta+=0.1 )
    {

        for(double phi = 0; phi <= M_PI ; phi+=0.1)
        {

            double sphere_x = obj_x + r*cos(theta)*sin(phi);
            double sphere_y = obj_y + r*sin(theta)*sin(phi);
            double sphere_z = obj_z + + r*cos(phi);

            string text = to_string(sphere_x) + " , " + to_string(sphere_y)+ " , " + to_string(sphere_z);
            positions << text << endl;

            rw::math::Transform3D<> transformation_matrix = transform(obj_x,obj_y,obj_z,sphere_x,sphere_y,sphere_z);

            string text2 = to_string(transformation_matrix.R().e()(0,2)) + " , "  + to_string(transformation_matrix.R().e()(1,2)) + " , " + to_string(transformation_matrix.R().e()(2,2));
            string text1 = to_string(transformation_matrix.R().e()(0,1)) + " , "  + to_string(transformation_matrix.R().e()(1,1)) + " , " + to_string(transformation_matrix.R().e()(2,1));
            string text0 = to_string(transformation_matrix.R().e()(0,0)) + " , "  + to_string(transformation_matrix.R().e()(1,0)) + " , " + to_string(transformation_matrix.R().e()(2,0));

            rotations_z << text2 << endl;
            rotations_y << text1 << endl;
            rotations_x << text0 << endl;

            if(count == 32) //TODO: Why...... is this occuring?
            {
                //cout << "Theta: " << theta << " Phi: " << phi << endl;
                //cout << sphere_x << " , " << sphere_y <<" , "<< sphere_z << endl;
                count = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                count++;
            }

            out.push_back(transformation_matrix);
        }
    }

    positions.close();
    rotations_z.close();
    rotations_y.close();
    rotations_x.close();
    cout << endl;
    cout <<"Object at: " << obj_x << "," << obj_y << "," << obj_z << endl;
    cout << "done " << endl;
    return out;
}
```

What am I trying to do, I am trying to orbit a robot endeffector  around an object in the center. The trajectory of the endeffector is an sphere where the endeffector should always point in to the object.  The sphere function should compute all transformation matrices which move the robot arm to the different position on the sphere with a given rotation, and the inverse kinematics should compute all the different Q-states, given an `x,y,z` which is the actual displacement to the object itself.

I am not quite sure where my error could be at, but I think it might either be at `transform` function where I generate my desired transformation matrix, or in `invKin` where I create `du`, I think I might have made an mistake in creating `du(3)`,  `du(4)`, `du(5)`

The libraries I've been using is Eigen, [robwork](http://www.robwork.dk/apidoc/nightly/rw/) (basically all rw::) if anyone want to look syntax through.

**Update**

Based on @ghanimmukhtar I began checking for singularities for the jacobian.. Which seems in general supringsly low. I computed it for a list of random Q configurations which resulted into this...

```
Determinant: -0.0577779
Determinant: -0.0582286
Determinant: 0.0051402
Determinant: -0.0498886
Determinant: 0.0209685
Determinant: 0.00372222
Determinant: 0.047645
Determinant: 0.0442362
Determinant: -0.0799746
Determinant: 0.00194714
Determinant: 0.0228195
Determinant: 0.096449
Determinant: -0.0339612
Determinant: -0.00365521
Determinant: -0.030022
Determinant: 0.021347
Determinant: 0.0413364
Determinant: 0.0041136
Determinant: -0.0151192
Determinant: 0.0682926
Determinant: -0.0657176
Determinant: 0.0915473
Determinant: -0.00516008
Determinant: -0.0394664
Determinant: -0.00469664
Determinant: 0.0494431
Determinant: -0.00156804
Determinant: -0.0402393
Determinant: -0.0141511
Determinant: 0.0203508
Determinant: -0.0368337
Determinant: -0.0313431
Determinant: -0.0566811
Determinant: -0.00766113
Determinant: -0.051767
Determinant: -0.00815555
Determinant: 0.0564639
Determinant: 0.0764514
Determinant: -0.0501299
Determinant: -0.00056537
Determinant: -0.0308103
Determinant: -0.0091592
Determinant: 0.0602148
Determinant: -0.0051255
Determinant: 0.0426342
Determinant: -0.0850566
Determinant: -0.0353419
Determinant: 0.0448761
Determinant: -0.0103023
Determinant: -0.0123843
Determinant: -0.00160566
Determinant: 0.00558663
Determinant: 0.0173488
Determinant: 0.0170783
Determinant: 0.0588363
Determinant: -0.000788464
Determinant: 0.052941
Determinant: 0.064341
Determinant: 0.00084967
Determinant: 0.00716674
Determinant: -0.0978426
Determinant: -0.0585773
Determinant: 0.038732
Determinant: -0.00489957
Determinant: -0.0460029
Determinant: 0.00269656
Determinant: 0.000600619
Determinant: -0.0408527
Determinant: -0.00115296
Determinant: 0.013114
Determinant: 0.0366423
Determinant: 0.0495209
Determinant: -0.042201
Determinant: -0.036663
Determinant: -0.103452
Determinant: -0.0119054
Determinant: 0.0692284
Determinant: -0.00717832
Determinant: 0.00729104
Determinant: 0.0126415
Determinant: -0.00515246
Determinant: -0.0556505
Determinant: 0.000670701
Determinant: -0.0545629
Determinant: 0.00251946
Determinant: 0.0405189
Determinant: 0.010928
Determinant: -0.00101032
Determinant: 0.0308612
Determinant: 0.0536183
Determinant: -0.0439223
Determinant: -0.0113453
Determinant: -0.0193872
Determinant: 0.0660165
Determinant: -0.00184695
Determinant: -0.106904
Determinant: 0.01246
Determinant: -0.00883772
Determinant: 0.0601036
Determinant: 0.0468602
Determinant: 0.0513812
Determinant: -0.000663089
Determinant: -0.00392395
Determinant: 0.0710837
Determinant: 0.0629583
Determinant: -0.0464579
Determinant: 0.0257618
Determinant: -0.0193227
Determinant: 0.00388693
Determinant: -0.02003
Determinant: 0.0191158
Determinant: -0.00159198
Determinant: -0.0702308
Determinant: -0.0242876
Determinant: -0.00934638
Determinant: -0.00221986
Determinant: -0.0268925
Determinant: 0.0596055
Determinant: -0.00925273
Determinant: -0.0167357
Determinant: 0.0596476
Determinant: -0.00515798
Determinant: -0.00324081
Determinant: -0.00321565
Determinant: 0.0669645
Determinant: -0.0342913
Determinant: -0.000342155
Determinant: -0.0104422
Determinant: -0.0410489
Determinant: -0.0246036
Determinant: 0.0208562
Determinant: -0.0692963
Determinant: 0.000839091
Determinant: -0.049308
Determinant: -0.0349338
Determinant: 0.0016057
Determinant: -0.00214381
Determinant: -0.0332965
Determinant: 0.0168007
Determinant: -0.0748581
Determinant: -0.00864737
Determinant: -0.0638044
Determinant: -0.00103911
Determinant: -0.00690918
Determinant: 0.000285789
Determinant: 0.0215414
Determinant: 0.0560827
Determinant: -0.0063201
Determinant: -0.00677609
Determinant: -0.00686829
Determinant: 0.0591599
Determinant: 0.0112705
Determinant: 0.0874784
Determinant: -0.0146124
Determinant: -0.0133718
Determinant: -0.0203801
Determinant: -0.0150386
Determinant: -0.102603
Determinant: -0.077111
Determinant: 0.021146
Determinant: 0.089761
Determinant: -0.0532867
Determinant: -0.0620632
Determinant: -0.0165414
Determinant: -0.0461426
Determinant: 0.00144256
Determinant: 0.00844777
Determinant: 0.0893306
Determinant: -0.0814478
Determinant: -0.0890507
Determinant: -0.0472091
Determinant: 0.0186799
Determinant: -0.00224087
Determinant: -0.0242662
Determinant: -0.00195303
Determinant: 0.014432
Determinant: 0.00185717
Determinant: -0.0354357
Determinant: -0.0427957
Determinant: -0.0380409
Determinant: 0.0627548
Determinant: 0.0397546
Determinant: 0.0570439
Determinant: 0.106265
Determinant: 0.0382001
Determinant: -0.0240826
Determinant: -0.0866264
Determinant: 0.024184
Determinant: 0.0841286
Determinant: -0.0303611
Determinant: -0.0337029
Determinant: -0.0202875
Determinant: 0.0643731
Determinant: -0.0475265
Determinant: -0.00928736
Determinant: -0.00373402
Determinant: 0.0636828
Determinant: 0.0122532
Determinant: 0.0398141
Determinant: -0.0563998
Determinant: -0.0778303
Determinant: 0.0164747
Determinant: 0.0314815
Determinant: 0.0744507
Determinant: -0.0897675
Determinant: 0.0260324
Determinant: -0.0734512
Determinant: 0.000234548
Determinant: -0.0238522
Determinant: -0.0849523
Determinant: 0.0204877
Determinant: -0.0715147
Determinant: 0.0703858
Determinant: -0.0142186
Determinant: -0.101503
Determinant: 0.03966
Determinant: 4.69111e-05
Determinant: 0.0394428
Determinant: 0.0409131
Determinant: 8.90995e-05
Determinant: -0.00841189
Determinant: -0.0671323
Determinant: 0.00805167
Determinant: -0.00292435
Determinant: 0.0507716
Determinant: 0.0493995
Determinant: 0.00629414
Determinant: -0.0428982
Determinant: -0.0446924
Determinant: 0.0776236
Determinant: 0.00440478
Determinant: -0.0463321
Determinant: -0.00247224
Determinant: -0.0199861
Determinant: 0.0267022
Determinant: 0.0184179
Determinant: 0.0104588
Determinant: 0.116535
Determinant: -0.0857382
Determinant: -0.0477216
Determinant: 0.0286968
Determinant: 0.0387932
Determinant: 0.042856
Determinant: -0.0964
Determinant: 0.0320456
Determinant: -0.0676327
Determinant: 0.0156632
Determinant: 0.0548582
Determinant: 0.0394791
Determinant: 0.0863353
Determinant: -0.0568753
Determinant: -0.00953039
Determinant: -0.0534666
Determinant: 0.0506779
Determinant: 0.00521034
Determinant: 0.0353338
Determinant: 0.0845463
Determinant: -0.00847695
Determinant: 0.015726
Determinant: -0.0648035
Determinant: 0.0170917
Determinant: 0.0045193
Determinant: -0.0195397
Determinant: 0.00630076
Determinant: -0.0137401
Determinant: 0.0209229
Determinant: 0.00382077
Determinant: -0.0588661
Determinant: -0.0923883
Determinant: -0.00726003
Determinant: -0.0411533
Determinant: 0.00544489
Determinant: 0.0101791
Determinant: 0.0903306
Determinant: -0.0590416
Determinant: -0.0377112
Determinant: -0.0150455
Determinant: 0.0793066
Determinant: 0.0425759
Determinant: -0.040728
Determinant: -0.0376792
Determinant: -0.0387703
Determinant: -0.0232208
Determinant: 0.0506747
Determinant: -0.0284409
Determinant: 0.000536999
Determinant: -0.0289103
Determinant: -0.00586449
Determinant: -0.0805586
Determinant: 0.0133906
Determinant: -0.00311773
Determinant: 0.0184798
Determinant: -0.00981978
Determinant: -0.0491601
Determinant: 0.0452526
Determinant: 0.00411708
Determinant: -0.0515142
Determinant: 0.0121114
Determinant: 0.00636972
Determinant: -0.0126048
Determinant: -0.0412662
Determinant: 0.00195264
Determinant: -0.0726478
Determinant: 0.0692254
Determinant: -0.0256477
Determinant: 0.0702529
Determinant: -0.0052493
Determinant: 0.0625172
Determinant: 0.00282606
Determinant: 0.0229033
Determinant: 0.0558893
Determinant: 0.0766217
Determinant: -0.00388679
Determinant: -0.0193821
Determinant: -0.00718189
Determinant: -0.0864566
Determinant: 0.0809026
Determinant: -0.0398232
Determinant: -0.00224801
Determinant: 0.0333072
Determinant: -0.0212002
Determinant: 0.00371396
Determinant: 0.0162035
Determinant: -0.0811845
Determinant: 0.0148128
Determinant: 0.0372953
Determinant: 0.00351286
Determinant: -0.00103575
Determinant: 0.0384813
Determinant: 0.00752738
Determinant: -0.0248252
Determinant: -0.106768
Determinant: -0.0192333
Determinant: -0.026543
Determinant: -0.0222608
Determinant: -0.0487862
Determinant: 0.00376402
Determinant: -0.0329469
Determinant: 0.00266775
Determinant: 0.0762491
Determinant: 0.0159609
Determinant: -0.0190175
Determinant: -0.0338969
Determinant: -0.0631867
Determinant: -0.0238901
Determinant: 0.107709
Determinant: -7.74935e-05
Determinant: -0.0468996
Determinant: 0.0462787
Determinant: 0.0387825
Determinant: 0.0753388
Determinant: -0.000279933
Determinant: 0.00638663
Determinant: -0.00458034
Determinant: 0.0185849
Determinant: -0.00543503
Determinant: -0.0520309
Determinant: -0.0234638
Determinant: 0.0593986
Determinant: -0.00036774
Determinant: 0.00960819
Determinant: -0.00685314
Determinant: -0.000176925
Determinant: 0.0207583
Determinant: -0.0337003
Determinant: -0.0534818
Determinant: 0.0142158
Determinant: -0.0728077
Determinant: 0.0246877
Determinant: -0.0660952
Determinant: -0.0466
Determinant: 0.0915457
Determinant: -0.00340539
Determinant: 0.00815076
Determinant: -0.0751806
Determinant: -0.00617677
Determinant: 0.0019761
Determinant: -0.0016673
Determinant: 0.0310364
Determinant: 0.0483121
Determinant: -0.00664964
Determinant: 0.0659273
Determinant: -0.019015
Determinant: 0.0087627
Determinant: 0.0267279
Determinant: 0.0253497
Determinant: 0.00246292
Determinant: -0.0684746
Determinant: -0.0234524
Determinant: -0.0197933
Determinant: 0.0120796
Determinant: -0.0192703
Determinant: 0.0853956
Determinant: 0.0388196
Determinant: -0.0599305
Determinant: -0.0626148
Determinant: 0.0258541
Determinant: -0.0341273
Determinant: 0.0972889
Determinant: -0.0306585
Determinant: 0.0188553
Determinant: 0.00247702
Determinant: -0.00368989
Determinant: -0.0951982
Determinant: 0.0113578
Determinant: 0.000762509
Determinant: -0.0225219
Determinant: 0.0414059
Determinant: -0.0244409
Determinant: -0.0425728
Determinant: 0.04275
Determinant: -0.0413427
Determinant: -0.00556264
Determinant: -0.0894398
Determinant: -0.0193197
Determinant: -0.00788038
Determinant: -0.00455421
Determinant: -0.0788177
Determinant: 0.0415381
Determinant: -0.0346766
Determinant: -0.0748027
Determinant: 0.0087688
Determinant: -0.0968796
Determinant: 0.0683526
Determinant: -0.00996678
Determinant: 0.00955922
Determinant: -0.0914706
Determinant: 0.0728304
Determinant: 0.0541784
Determinant: 0.0457072
Determinant: -0.0299529
Determinant: -0.0096473
Determinant: -0.0142643
Determinant: -0.0684794
Determinant: 0.00281004
Determinant: -0.03252
Determinant: -0.0144637
Determinant: 0.0294154
Determinant: 0.00574353
Determinant: -0.019569
Determinant: 0.00492446
Determinant: -0.0526394
Determinant: -0.000870143
Determinant: -0.0180984
Determinant: -0.0144104
Determinant: 0.0456077
Determinant: -0.0113433
Determinant: 0.00377549
Determinant: -0.0775854
Determinant: -0.0336789
Determinant: -0.0744995
Determinant: -0.0427397
Determinant: 0.0300061
Determinant: -0.0326518
Determinant: -0.0333735
Determinant: -0.0284057
Determinant: -0.00999835
Determinant: -0.0380404
Determinant: 0.00648521
Determinant: 0.0449298
Determinant: 0.0120318
Determinant: -0.0230653
Determinant: -0.00934067
Determinant: -0.0175326
Determinant: -0.0799447
Determinant: 0.0679027
Determinant: -0.00670324
Determinant: -0.0841748
Determinant: 0.0236213
Determinant: 0.0386624
Determinant: -0.0239495
Determinant: 0.076976
Determinant: -0.00997484
Determinant: 0.025157
Determinant: -0.0654046
Determinant: 0.0090564
Determinant: 0.00129045
Determinant: -0.105119
Determinant: 0.0976925
Determinant: -0.105149
Determinant: -0.0465851
Determinant: 0.00237453
Determinant: -0.0456927
Determinant: 0.0328236
Determinant: -0.0914691
Determinant: -0.0157904
Determinant: -0.00170804
Determinant: -0.014797
Determinant: 0.00464912
Determinant: -0.035118
Determinant: -0.0242306
Determinant: 0.0081405
Determinant: 0.0733502
Determinant: -0.0860252
Determinant: -0.0511219
Determinant: -0.0925647
Determinant: 0.0495087
Determinant: -0.0515914
Determinant: -0.044318
Determinant: 0.000900043
Determinant: 0.0632521
Determinant: 0.00957955
Determinant: 0.00598059
Determinant: 0.0179513
Determinant: 0.0952263
```

`dx,dy,dz` is a is the distance between tcp and an object i want to keep in sight. The sphere is like a safety zone, but is mainly used to compute the orientation of the tool.

Comment: If the sign of determinant of the Jacobian is changing, it is likely that you have a singularity in between. Note that the "smallness" of the value of determinant is a relative term.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit hard to know the exact cause of the error without having the (RobWork), I tried to install it following the link your provided, but I ran into some problems and I don't have the time to fix them at the moment. But I can point you to some issues that might be the source of your problem:

1. The `transform` method you are given in this code doesn't have a return statement, though you have declared it to return a `rw::math::Transform3D<>`.
2. If you are near a singularity the inverse kinematics will normally return high values. The singularities depend on the robot structure you are using. You can detect this by seeing the determinant of your jacobian matrix, the closer it is to zero the closer you are to a singularity.
3. Also I don't understand why you use the line `rw::math::Q dq(q)`, because normally the inverse kinematic should return `dq` if your desired displacement is small enough (i.e. `du`) so normally you should be able to add it directly to add `q` directly to the `q_current`, so may be it could be of interest to check the raw values for these variables.

Also may be it could be more accurate to use a polynomial interpolater to produce the `du` and then run the whole inverse kinematic in a while loop with a `boos::timer` for instance. I have actually developed and inverse kinematic for Crustcrawler arm that does that, but I use joint velocity control directly since the output of the inverse kinematic is actually joints velocity, also I am not binding myself to move in sphere I just give a goal position and duration and the model drive the end effecter nicely to it via joints velocities.

If you have more details please share them, it could help in identifying the issue more effectively. Like how `invKin` is called? and what exactly are those parameters passed to it (i.e. `x, y, z`)?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have been debugging it myself a bit, (After a bit of a break) and found the error with the `transform` you mention in 1) and `dq` in3). The library itself is pretty tricky to install, and might tends to be troublesome, I realize in retrospect that a install guide would be have been ideal here.. But yeah. I didn't think anyone would try to run it.. Thanks for trying :). I have been debugging the math (visulizing vectors and such stuff) for the `sphere` and `transform` function, and they seem to be correct. I think my error must be due to the way I compute `du` (...)

Comment: I am not sure how I should compute the difference between rotation vector as a 3 numeric values?... Taking the difference between the two 3d vectors would result in one vector, and not a numeric number describing the rotation from the current state to the desired state.

Comment: The determinant were computed to Determinant: 2.67004e-40...
Probably a singularity...

Comment: hmm... It seems pretty hard to find a start configuration which jacobian doesn't entail in to a singularity...?

Comment: Moving it to a position with less singularity computes reasonable Q's.. but the trajectory isn't spheric as hoped. ...

I think i might be because of the start configuration, and the large displacement it has to make to reach the goal.

Comment: So.. I think basically my issue has been that the distance i wanted to travel was too large, and singularities.. So i tried to fix them.. but things still doesn't seem right..

Comment: the axis is pointing in the wrong direction..

Comment: @James potter, sorry I can't get back to you now, but I will do ASAP.

Comment: Example can be seen here: https://giphy.com/gifs/l4HojuDYt0UtdM4Cc